# cassandra All hosts tried for query failed CassandraCSharpDriver

Tags: c#, cassandra

I tried to connect cassandra from virtual machine to main machine and use it with CassandraCSharpDriver. The error is "All hosts tried for query failed (tried :: SocketException 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')".
I already have cassandra tested on main machine (x.x.x.1) and it worked, then I create 3 virtual machine with cassandra on it (x.x.x.2),(x.x.x.3),(x.x.x.4) but none of them worked on main machine. I even tried add all of the IP in the .yaml config file but doesn't seem work, althought x2, x3, x4 connected to each others on virtualbox with the same way. Is there anything I need to check in order to connect 3 virtual machine to main machine. Here is what I have done: config virt machine network to host-only; config virt machine IP to static; config .yaml file both virt and main machine; create keyspace, table. Here is the code create ISession

```
public static DataConnection Ins
{
    get
    {
        if (_Ins == null)
            _Ins = new DataConnection();
        return _Ins;
    }
    set
    {
        _Ins = value;
    }
}
private static DataConnection _Ins;
private DataConnection()
{
    session = getConnect();
    session.Execute("use KeySpace;");
}

public ISession session;
private string IP = "x.x.x.4"; 
private string Datacenter = "datacenter1";
public ISession getConnect()
{
    return session = Cluster.Builder()
                         .AddContactPoints(IP)
                         .WithPort(9042)
                         .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(Datacenter))
                         .Build()
                         .Connect();
}
```

And here the using part:

```
private void LoginBtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "Query sth";

        Cassandra.RowSet row = DataConnection.Ins.session.Execute(query);
        if (row.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            //Do sth
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to join the 3 new VMs to the first node?  Or are you asking why you cannot connect with your C# code?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I want to know how to connect 3 VMs to the first node. I already test connecting C# code with the first node.

Comment: It's still hard to follow just what is happening.  But I will say that it sounds like the VMs are in their own private network, and cannot get to the 1st node.  The 1st node also cannot get into the VM network.  Basically, this is only going to work if the IPs of all nodes are resolvable by all other nodes.  If you're using something like VirtualBox, try putting the network in "bridge mode."  Or make sure that the VMs have external, resolvable IP addresses.

Comment: It true as Aaron said above, all I need is get the IP which that virtualbox use to communicate to main machine (using netstat -rn) and included it in the .yaml config file. Thanks you sir.